# DB when i upload my website in 000webhost.com

Tags: php, mysql, server

I have uploaded my website to 000webhost.com, but it shows this error:

[image]

I use the following code to connect to the database:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
global $connection;
$connection = mysqli_connect("000webhost","course_coordination","1122334455","id5418791_course_coordination");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_results = 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_client = 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_database = 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_server = 'utf8'");  
if(!$connection) {
    $err = 'Can Not Connected To Server';
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' style='max-width:500px; margin: 4px auto'>";
        echo $err;
    echo "</div>";
} 
?>
```

I think there an error in line 4. please help me with that

Comment: Please proof-read your question. Not very many people will be pleased with being addressed "hell".

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: There doesn't look like there's a problem to me. What error are you getting? We aren't Magic.

Comment: You might not want to put your database password on a public forum

Comment: You might want to let us know what happens? _"I know there's a problem"_ isn't much for us to go on. Error messages? Failing to connect? Your computer catches flames? Also, if you're having issues with a specific service, you should start by contacting the service provider. SO isn't a general helpdesk for anything internet.

Comment: `000webhost` isn't a valid hostname. Contact the hosting provider and ask them for the correct connection details.

Comment: @SamLittlefair it is not a real password

Comment: you're probably trying to connect to a remote server with a free account where it doesn't allow that. If this is the case, then you need to pay for hosting. That, or the credentials are incorrect.

Comment: Your connection parameters are wrong. Specifically the hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On all the methods you need to edit three lines only because 000webhost uses localhost as the servername (servername should not be changed).

Username - The username assigned to the database. It can be found on your 000webhost control panel -> Manage database. Username is combined of your
000webhost username and the name you created.

Password - a password which you set for your username of this database.

Database - The name of your database. It can be found on your 000webhost control panel -> Manage database. Database name is combined of your 000webhost username and the name of the database you created.

**Refer this link:**https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/what-is-mysql-hostname-24

Comment: Thankkkkk youuuu so much